# How to erase all pixels of certain color on every file inside a folder?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, imagemagick

Is there a easy way to convert all images in a folder, so every pixel with a specific color is removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define what "removed" means. If you mean replaced with some other (background) color, you can convert a single file like this:

```
convert -fill REPLACEMENT_COLOR -opaque ORIGINAL_COLOR \
        ORIGINAL_IMAGE MODIFIED_IMAGE
```

If by "removed" you mean make pixels transparent, then you can convert a single file like this:

```
convert -transparent ORIGINAL_COLOR ORIGINAL_IMAGE MODIFIED_IMAGE
```

Where ORIGINAL_IMAGE and MODIFIED_IMAGE are your input and output image files respectively and ORIGINAL_COLOR and REPLACEMENT_COLOR are original and replacement colors in [ImageMagick color format](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/color.php).

Now, for example, this will replace all red pixels with white pixels in all images in the current directory and save them with names prefixed with "modified_":

```
for f in *; do
    convert -fill white -opaque red "$f" "modified_$f"
done
```